# My model trains good, but produces bad MSE?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am getting very bad number from mine MSE and I do not understand where I am doing wrong. I know I cannot judge by my training but I believe my model is trained well.

```
Optimization Finished!
MSE: 3593717153792.000000
Training Time: 81.99638080596924
```

I hope you can give me an idea where to look and maybe what to do?
This is how my model looks like:

```
# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.0001
training_epochs = 100
batch_size = 500
display_step = 1
# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 480  # 1st layer number of features
n_hidden_2 = 240  # 2nd layer number of features
n_hidden_3 = 240  # 3rd layer number of features
n_hidden_4 = 256  # 4th layer number of features
n_out = 1
n_input = X_train.shape[1]
total_len = X_train.shape[0]
```

All the layers are with RELU as activation function except the Output layer which is with linear.

This is my cost function:

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(tf.transpose(pred) - y) / y)
```

this is my data testing:

```
pred_y = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={x: X_test})
mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(tf.transpose(pred_y) - Y_test))
print("MSE: %4f" % sess.run(mse))
```

My data consists best 59 features (out of 90) and predicts one continuous value only. For training I am using  105566 normalized samples of data. My normalization was done using sklearn:

```
    batch_x_norm = preprocessing.scale(batch_x)
```

And my validation set is 13196 samples.
Thank you in advance for the help!.

Comment: I did a stupid mistake by not normalizing my validation set after it the results are not that big, but still not satisfying:
MAE: 88834.726562
MRE: 0.355447

Comment: My primary guess would be either: 1. the magnitude of features and/or y is too large; 2. the parameters were initialized wrong; 3. some of the `y`s are too close to zero so that the `cost` is highly biased. Please try scaling features (using z-score perhaps) and y to proper ranges and using `tf.variance_scaling_initializer` for weight initialization if you have not done so.

Comment: options 2 and 3 I think are not the problem, however 1. my values are very different from each other but as I said I normalized them. I normalized the test and the training input
Training input:
`batch_x_norm = preprocessing.scale(batch_x)`
Test input:
 `X_test_norm = preprocessing.scale(X_test)
pred_y = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={x: X_test_norm})`

 I cannot understand what you mean by normalizing the weights, I am currently setting them the following way:

`'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1], 0, 0.1, name='h1')),
'h2': ...`